# PyQt: eventFilter to get mouse position in a semi-transparent window

Tags: qt, pyqt

I want to make:

1. a semi-transparent fullscreen window (`rgba(0,0,0,180)`).
2. while moving mouse, display absolute position on label.
3. user can press on it to get the absolute position of the mouse.

However I cannot achieve the second one. When moving mouse on it, label won't update mouse's position. But I found when moving out of label (after removing `layout.setMargin(0)` and `layout.setSpacing(0)`), it works.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys, os, math
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class ScreenPositionLabel(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ScreenPositionLabel, self).__init__()

        self.setStyleSheet("background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 180); color:#fff;")
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
        #self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_OpaquePaintEvent, False)
        #self.setStyleSheet("QMainWindow{opacity:0.5;}")

        self.label = QtGui.QLabel("Please click on screen")
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

        layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.label)

        # remove margin and padding
        layout.setMargin(0)
        layout.setSpacing(0)

        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.installEventFilter(self)

        self.label.show()
        self.show()

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if (event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseMove and
            event.buttons() == QtCore.Qt.NoButton):
                pos = event.pos()
                self.label.setText('Please click on screen. ( %d : %d )' % (pos.x(), pos.y()))
        elif event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonPress:
            pos = event.pos()
            print('( %d : %d )' % (pos.x(), pos.y()))
            self.close()
        return QtGui.QWidget.eventFilter(self, source, event)

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

main_window = ScreenPositionLabel()
app.exec_()
```

Any way to solve this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your 4 questions:

> 1) I want to make: a semi-transparent fullscreen window (rgba(0,0,0,180)).

Yes, you can. Please use [`QWidget.setWindowOpacity (self, float level)`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qwidget.html#setWindowOpacity).

> 2) I want to make: while moving mouse, display absolute position on label.

I recommend using `QWidget.mouseMoveEvent (self, QMouseEvent)` to get current position your mouse and enable `QWidget.setMouseTracking (self, bool enable)` for track all mouse movement.

[`QWidget.setMouseTracking (self, bool enable)`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qwidget.html#setMouseTracking)

[`QWidget.mouseMoveEvent (self, QMouseEvent)`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qwidget.html#mouseMoveEvent)

> 3) I want to make: user can press on it to get the absolute position of the mouse.

[Using `QWidget.mousePressEvent (self, QMouseEvent)` to track when mouse press.](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qwidget.html#mousePressEvent)

> 4) However I cannot achieve the second one. When moving mouse on it, label won't update mouse's position. But I found when moving out of label (after removing `layout.setMargin(0)` and `layout.setSpacing(0))`, it works.

Because in default layout height of `QLabel` has spacing & margin, then real area isn't all area widget solve it is your solution is OK.

Full example for your solution:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class QCustomLabel (QtGui.QLabel):
    def __init__ (self, parent = None):
        super(QCustomLabel, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.setTextLabelPosition(0, 0)
        self.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

    def mouseMoveEvent (self, eventQMouseEvent):
        self.setTextLabelPosition(eventQMouseEvent.x(), eventQMouseEvent.y())
        QtGui.QWidget.mouseMoveEvent(self, eventQMouseEvent)

    def mousePressEvent (self, eventQMouseEvent):
        if eventQMouseEvent.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            QtGui.QMessageBox.information(self, 'Position', '( %d : %d )' % (self.x, self.y))
        QtGui.QWidget.mousePressEvent(self, eventQMouseEvent)

    def setTextLabelPosition (self, x, y):
        self.x, self.y = x, y
        self.setText('Please click on screen ( %d : %d )' % (self.x, self.y))

class QCustomWidget (QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__ (self, parent = None):
        super(QCustomWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowOpacity(0.7)
        # Init QLabel
        self.positionQLabel = QCustomLabel(self)
        # Init QLayout
        layoutQHBoxLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        layoutQHBoxLayout.addWidget(self.positionQLabel)
        layoutQHBoxLayout.setMargin(0)
        layoutQHBoxLayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.setLayout(layoutQHBoxLayout)
        self.showFullScreen()


myQApplication = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
myQTestWidget = QCustomWidget()
myQTestWidget.show()
myQApplication.exec_()
```

Comment: And great detailed explanations~!